# Ubuntu. Keys emulation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

There are tenkeyless (slim) keyboards with don't have numpad and dont' have emulation of numpad, so I would like to emulate numpad on UIOJKLM<> buttons on holding ALT or WIN key.
Is there application for that for Linux (freeware or paid), preferably free or open source ?